# What to do and why is this allowed?

Tags: discussion

Okay so just a few minutes ago I lost some reputation points and went to investigate. What I found was that a question I had an accepted answer for was edited and completely changed into another question.

The question is: [Active class for the slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957556/active-class-for-the-slider)

What I would like to know is what should be done in this case? Also if the SO user edits a question with an already accepted answer does this not go through any **reviews**?

Comment: Nothing you can do about the reputation but the question should not have been changed. Notice the comment at the top: _"Thats too Bad.I have to edit my old question here in order to write a new question and That is because my other 2 questions are closed. OK ANYWAY!!! "_

Comment: The question has been rolled back. But I bet the OP is question banned.

Comment: I figured as much with the rep, that's no big deal. Sounds to me like we need some type of review for this strange case. Like if the question content is changed by more than 75% it needs to go through something like a question edit review?

Comment: @StevenFarley That would be a double edged sword. We don't want to put in any obstacles in the way of people adding relevant details to a stub question.

Comment: I've also locked the question as well as commented at the person who posted/edited the content.  Let us know if it keeps up (through flag or meta post or comment at a moderator) and we'll take care of it.

Comment: The asker's other closed (and seriously downvoted) question was edited in the same way. I've rolled that back as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to roll back the edit.

You might also want to keep an eye on the question so that if the OP re-edits you can flag it. Don't roll back the edit again, you don't want to get involved in an edit war.

The moderators can lock the question for an hour or so (or longer if necessary) to give enough time to contact the OP (if necessary) and get them to stop.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If for some reason a re-edit was to be done, what type of flag would be preferred in this case?

Comment: @StevenFarley - use a custom flag to explain the situation.

Comment: @StevenFarley The user did it again about 10 minutes ago - I've rolled back and flagged for moderator attention

Comment: Gah, I hate it when that happens. What Chris F said here is precisely what you should do, we're happy to intervene when this happens. It's simply not acceptable to waste people's time like that.